# Change the size of a GameObject in a certain timespan

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject, and in a specific timespan it needs to shrink.

So basicaly my GameObject its size is 100x100, i want it to shrink to 10x10 in exactly 1 second.
Now i could use `InvokeRepeating` but that would only make it jump from 100x100 to 10x10.
I want it to smoothly go from 100x100 to 10x10.
There is no code yet, im trying to figure out how that would be done because using `Update` wouldn't give me the right results.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with `Coroutine` and `Vector.Lerp` in while loop. This is better than using the `Invoke` or `InvokeRepeating` function.

```
bool isScaling = false;

IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject objToScale, Vector3 newScale, float duration)
{
    if (isScaling)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    isScaling = true;

    Vector3 currentScale = objToScale.transform.localScale;

    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 tempVector = Vector3.Lerp(currentScale, newScale, counter / duration);
        objToScale.transform.localScale = tempVector;
        yield return null;
    }

    isScaling = false;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public GameObject gameObjectToScale;
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(gameObjectToScale, new Vector3(2, 2, 2), 1f));
}
```